# Razor, multiple validation (Null or [0])?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, razor

This is my code:

```
var document = '@(Model.Article.ListFiles == null || Model.Article.ListFiles.Any(f => f == 0) == true ? "isNull" : "notNull")'
```

Doesnt fail, but it should return null.
However on console i see this:

```
document = notNull
```

I must doing something wrong.
When ListFiles comes on null works, however i think is not working when value is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the following assumes that `Model.Article.ListFiles` is a `List<int>`.

You should negate the `Any()` test, like this:

```
var document = '@(Model.Article.ListFiles == null || !Model.Article.ListFiles.Any(f => f == 0) ? "isNull" : "notNull")'
```

This will return "isNull" if ListFiles is null or has **NO** 0 (zero) values. If you want to return "isNull" if ListFiles is null or has at least one 0 (zero) value, do this:

```
var document = '@(Model.Article.ListFiles == null || Model.Article.ListFiles.Any(f => f == 0) ? "isNull" : "notNull")'
```